# Using extra-var to call a defined variable in ansible

Tags: variables, ansible

Is this possible? I have a playbook looking like this:

vars: 
    BDNAME: ""

```
  - name: Add a tenant using a JSON string
     aci_bd:
      tenant: "common"
      bd: "{{ BDNAME }}"
      vrf: "PIGGE"
      hostname: '1.1.1.1' 
      username: "x"
      password: "x"
      use_ssl: yes
      validate_certs: false
```

It works if i provide an extra variable in the commandline:

ansible-playbook apic.yml  -i server.yml --extra-vars BDNAME='pooh'

Then BDNAME gets the value pooh.
But is there any way that i can define pooh as a variable. So if i run the playbook like i just did, BDNAME get the value of that variable.

So something like
  vars: 
    BDNAME: ""
    POOH: nisse

Then BDNAME should be nisse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define BDNAME in playbook directly from the extra variable POOH. That should do what you want. But it would be easier to use POOH instead of BDNAME.

Here is a example playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    BDNAME: "{{ POOH }}"
  tasks:
    - name: print BDNAME
      debug:
        msg: "{{ BDNAME }}"
```

if you call it with:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml  -e '{"POOH": "Oliver"}'
```

you will see:

```
TASK [print BDNAME] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Oliver"
}
```